# NDSolve : Boundary conditions of lower order

Tags: differential-equations

Given the (dummy) problem

```
InitialConditions = 
   {
    y[s, 0] == 1,
    x[s, 0] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 1][x][s, 0] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 1][y][s, 0] == 0
  };
 BoundaryConditions = 
   {
    x[0, t] == 0,
    x[1, t] == 0,
    y[0, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + Derivative[1, 0][x][0, t]),
    y[1, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + Derivative[1, 0][x][1, t])
    };
 EOM =
   {
    Derivative[0, 2][x][s, t] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 2][y][s, t] == 1
    };
 NDSolve[Join[InitialConditions, BoundaryConditions, EOM], {x[s, t], y[s, t]}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This is obviously a second order problem with solution

```
x[s,t] = 0
y[s,t] = 1 + t^2/2
```

I would imagine it easy to numerically solve, but Mathematica complains that `Boundary condition should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation.`  The only derivatives in the boundary condition are of first order in `s`, while the equations are second order in `t`.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative boundary condition is specified with respect to the wrong variable.

[image]

```
InitialConditions = {
y[s, 0] == 1, 
x[s, 0] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 1][x][s, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 1][y][s, 0] == 0};
BoundaryConditions = {
x[0, t] == 0,
x[1, t] == 0, 
y[0, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + Derivative[0, 1][x][0, t]), 
y[1, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + Derivative[0, 1][x][1, t])};
EOM = {
Derivative[0, 2][x][s, t] == 0,
Derivative[0, 2][y][s, t] == 1};

sol=NDSolve[Join[InitialConditions, BoundaryConditions, EOM], {x[s, t], 
y[s, t]}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[{y[s, t], x[s, t]} /. sol], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDITED:**

In general there should be as many boundary ot initial conditions as the highest order of corresponding partial derivative. In your's case "s" function has no derivative.

$$\frac{\partial^{2}\ x(s,t)}{\partial t^{2}}=0, \frac{\partial^{2}\ y(s,t)}{\partial t^{2}}=1$$

All functions x=w[s] and y=w[s] are solutions.

Comment: In the problem that I require, the derivative is actually given wrt the `s` coordinate as in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the dummy problem is sufficiently representative: The system factors through `x`, so to speak.  In other words, we can first solve for `x` and then for `y`.  An alternative approach is to solve iteratively, starting with a test function for `x` to be used for `Derivative[1, 0][x]` and hoping the iteration converges.  If these methods are insufficient, maybe a new question with a more representative problem could be posted.

**The issue with the OP's set up**

The problem, I think, is that roughly the solvers in `NDSolve` solve for the highest-order derivatives in the PDE/ODE using integration schemes that are functions of lower order derivatives.  When the initial/boundary conditions define the variable being solved for in terms of higher-order derivatives, `NDSolve` complains that it is not set up to do that.  I do not know if there is a workaround, other than perhaps manually coding up a solver.  (I've never done it nor seen it done, but perhaps one can solve implicitly for `Derivative[1, 0][x]` in the spatial discretization and proceed from there.  That's a random guess, by the way, which I do not intend follow up at present.)

**Factoring the system**

We can delete the `x` or `y` components from the system:

```
solver = Inactivate[
   NDSolve[Join[InitialConditions, BoundaryConditions, EOM],
    {x, y}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}], NDSolve];

solver /. l_List /; ! FreeQ[l, x | y] :> DeleteCases[l, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, y]]
solver /. l_List /; ! FreeQ[l, x | y] :> Cases[l, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, y]]
(*
  Inactive[NDSolve][{x[s, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][x][s, 0] == 0, 
      x[0, t] == 0, x[1, t] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][x][s, t] == 0},
     {x}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
  Inactive[NDSolve][{y[s, 0] == 1, 
      Derivative[0, 1][y][s, 0] == 0, 
      y[0, t] == 1 + (1/2)*t^2*(1 + Derivative[1, 0][x][0, t]), 
      y[1, t] == 1 + (1/2)*t^2*(1 + Derivative[1, 0][x][1, t]), 
      Derivative[0, 2][y][s, t] == 1}, {y}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
*)

{xsol} = Activate[
   solver /. l_List /; ! FreeQ[l, x | y] :> DeleteCases[l, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, y]]];
{ysol} = Activate[
   solver /. l_List /; ! FreeQ[l, x | y] :> Cases[l, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, y]] /. xsol];
sol = Join[xsol, ysol];

Plot3D[Evaluate[{y[s, t], x[s, t]} /. sol], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Iteration**

The dummy example converges immediately, which is not surprising.  I'm not sure if this will work in the actual use-cases.

We set up the PDE to use the previous solution for `Derivative[1, 0][x]`:

```
Clear[boundaryConditions];
initialConditions = {
   y[s, 0] == 1, Derivative[0, 1][x][s, 0] == 0,
   x[s, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][y][s, 0] == 0};
boundaryConditions[n_] := {
   x[0, t] == 0,
   x[1, t] == 0,
   y[0, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + (Derivative[1, 0][x][0, t] /. sol[n - 1])),
   y[1, t] == 1 + t^2/2*(1 + (Derivative[1, 0][x][1, t] /. sol[n - 1]))};
EOM = {Derivative[0, 2][x][s, t] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][y][s, t] == 1};
$maxIterations = 10;
```

Then we "guess" at a solution `sol[0]` for `x[s, t]`.  I picked `Sin[2 Pi s]` so as to miss the actual solution.

```
Clear[sol];
sol[0] = {x -> Function[{s, t}, Sin[2 Pi s]]};  (* initial guess *)
Do[
 {sol[n]} = NDSolve[Join[initialConditions, boundaryConditions[n], EOM],
   {x, y}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
 error = If[n <= 1,     (* might want a combination of relative/absolute error *)
   1,
   Max@ Abs@ With[{grid = x["Grid"] /. sol[n]},
        {Apply[x /. sol[n], grid, {2}] - Apply[x /. sol[n - 1], grid, {2}],
         Apply[y /. sol[n], grid, {2}] - Apply[y /. sol[n - 1], grid, {2}]}
        ]
   ];
 If[error < 10^-8,
  sol["Final"] = sol[n];
  sol["Iterations"] = n;
  sol["MaxError"] = error;
  Break[]],
 {n, $maxIterations}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[{y[s, t], x[s, t]} /. sol["Final"]],
  {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
(* same as above *)
```

Performance checks:

```
{sol["Iterations"], sol["MaxError"]}
(*  {3, 0.}  *)

GraphicsRow@ Table[
  Plot3D[Evaluate[{y[s, t], x[s, t]} /. sol[n]],
    {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> Automatic],
  {n, sol["Iterations"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I understood mathematica to use the "Method of Lines" where it discritises in one dimension (here space) and then uses finite difference approximations to the spacial derivatives.  Is there a good reason for "`NDSolve` complains that it is not set up to do that"?  Surely the method of lines can accommodate this.  Especially at a boundary...

Comment: @rspencer Yes, you're right about the "Method of Lines". I'm afraid I don't know if there is a good reason or not. It does seem, at least conceptually, one could use finite differences to approximate any purely spatial derivative, unless I'm missing something. You could do such a discretization yourself and apply `NDSolve` as in the "Method of Lines" tutorial. But I have no idea if any practical issues (e.g. poor error control) are significant. As I said, I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: I had considered discretising myself.  I think, at the moment, that will have to be my best bet.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help.  Good luck.

Comment: Hello, I faced the same error with this one: solve u_t=u_xx in (0,10)*(0,1), u_t=-u_x at x=0, u_t=u_x at x=1, Itried this

`NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], u[0, x] == 0,  
  Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0], 
  Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == -Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1]}, u, {t, 0, 
  10}, {x, 0, 1}]`

Thanks for any help.